# Correct way making a translation table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, translation

We currently use a translation table which looks like this:

```
|  id | type  | name     | lang  |  value   | 
|-----+-------+----------+-------+----------|
| 853 | text  | question |  en   | question |
| 854 | text  | question |  nl   |  vraag   |
```

So for each extra translation in another language we would have to add another row

Were thinking about changing it to a table which has a column for each country value (so you would just need to add 1 row).

So it would look like this:

```
| id  | type  | name     | lang  |  nl     |  en        |
|-----+-------+----------+-------+---------+------------+
| 853 | text  | question |  en   |  vraag  | question   |
```

- Are there any downsides to doing it the second way compared to the
  first one?
- How would you suggest creating a translation table like
  this?

Comment: Why not to join two tables, master one with `id,type,name` fields and nested with `id,master_id,lang,value`?

Comment: So for 1 translation i would have to add a "master translation" than add all the translations row by row?

Comment: No. I need to paste some code, so let’s see my answer.

Comment: I'm going to throw in a new option: .json files. I'm not even joking.
`$lang['master_key'] = 'chave mestra'` and then you just encode `$lang` with `json_encode` and `file_put_contents()` it to `pt.json`
then you just have to convert it back when you want to use it; No need for sql tables and would always be in one simple place to fetch :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not to join two tables, master one with `id,type,name` fields and nested with `id,master_id,lang,value`. For the given example that will be looking like:

```
ID      TYPE     NAME
 1      text     question

ID      MASTER_ID      LANG        TRANSLATION
 1      1              en          question
 2      1              nl          vraag
```

The translation set for one language is given by SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM `nested` WHERE `lang` = 'nl'
-- vraag
-- .....
```

The translation for the given term (e.g. `question`, having `id=1`):

```
SELECT * FROM `nested` WHERE `master_id` = 1 AND `lang` = 'nl' 
-- vraag
```

Comment: Only thing im wondering say i have a million translation in 10 languages. In this type of format i would need 10 times the rows + extra million master rows instead of the million rows in the second example wouldn't it be alot slower?

Comment: Whether you have million translations (are you Jimmy Wales, aren’t you?) you’d better maintain 10 subsequent tables for 10 languages, I guess. That’s the chicken-egg question about maintainability and performance.

Comment: if you use proper indexes you should not have any problems with fetching data for your ids.

Comment: you can also add another lookup table for your languages so you would have your "master_id", a language_id and your translated text.

Comment: @TheChaos This is what I suggested talking about 10 tables for 10 languages.

Comment: @TheChaos The more i think about it the more sense this is starting to make now you mentioned the indexes just couln't quite figure it out myself :P thanks for explaining.

Comment: @mudasobwa: You don't need 10 tables for 10 languages. Simply add another language to your languages table and use that id as reference in your translation table.

Comment: @mudasobwa Your right took a while to get why it would be better but it makes alot more sense now :)

Comment: @herriekrekel Glad to be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The downside of the second idea is that for every new language you want to add you have to change your database structure (following code changes to reflect that structure change) whereas the first only needs new rows (which keeps the same structure).

another plus for the first idea is that you really only need the space/memory for translations you add to the database. in the second approach you could have lots of empty fields in case you won't translate all texts.

a way to do it could be (an addition to the answer above from @mudasobwa):

```
Master Table:
| id | type | master_name |
|----+------+-------------|
|853 | text | question    |
|854 | text | answer      |

Language Table:
| id | language_name |
|----+---------------|
| 1  | english       |
| 2  | german        |

Translation Table:
| id | master_id | language_id | translation        |
|----+-----------+-------------+--------------------|
| 1  | 853       | 1           | question           |
| 1  | 854       | 2           | Frage              |
| 2  | 853       | 1           | answer             |
| 2  | 854       | 2           | Antwort            |
```

So if you have another language, add it to the language table and add the translations for your master texts for that language.

Adding indexes to the ids will help speeding up queries for the texts.

Comment: Thanks for addition, kinda made me understand why it would make sense to do it the way mudasobwa described

Answer (score 0):

Second way is much better:

- Keeps less place in Database.
- Loads faster.
- Easy to edit.

Comment: this approach would only make sense if you know beforehand which languages you will have and you won't have to add/remove some.

Comment: another addition to the "less place" argument: Every column you declare, even if not filled, will need space in your database, so this is wrong: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-physical-record.html

Comment: @TheChaos so would you suggest the answer below than where you have a master id than for each translation you put it in the secondary table with the linked master id?

Comment: @herriekrekel: Yes i would do that (in fact already did). We use the exact same type of structure for our data over here.